# Biblatex Replace URL label from "url:" and enclose URL with "<" and ">"

Tags: biblatex

I am using `biblatex` and I would like to replace the "url:" with "<" and ">" in my references section.

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{<}\url{#1}\bibstring{>}}
```

The `\DeclareFieldFormat` replacement appears to do what I want, but I cannot work out the correct way to insert the "<" and ">" in the replacement string.

How do I define less than and greater symbols in the `\DeclareFieldFormat` command?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a minimal (non-)working example?

Answer (score 2):

You only need `\bibstring` if you want to print a localisation string defined by `\NewBibliographyString`/`\DefineBibliographyStrings`/the `.lbx` files. Otherwise you can just insert the characters directly in a `\DeclareFieldFormat` directive, though I think it would be slightly nicer to us a macro

```
\newcommand*{\mkbiburlangle}[1]{<#1>}
% choose for example
%    {<#1>}
% or {\ensuremath{\langle}#1\ensuremath{\rangle}}
% or {\guilsinglleft#1\guilsinglright}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\mkbiburlangle{\url{#1}}}
```

For example

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}


\newcommand*{\mkbiburlangle}[1]{<#1>}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\mkbiburlangle{\url{#1}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{ctan}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: CTAN (2006). CTAN. The Comprehensive TeX Archive Network. <http://www.ctan.org> (visited on 01/10/2006).]